# Okta Reactivating Active Directory Users

Tags: powershell, okta

We have about 100 users that were disabled in AD, and thus Deprovisioned in Okta.  I'm trying to reactivate these users in Okta.  They were already enabled on AD.

I'm using the PowerShell module for Okta written by Matt Egan (https://github.com/mbegan/Okta-PSModule)  and I can take the user account from deprovisioned to Provisioned.  However, the account is no longer profiled by Active Directory.  Is there an API call that would allow me to make that final link?

```
PS C:\Users\perry.harris> oktaGetUserbyID -oOrg Contoso -userName joe.user@contoso.com
[ GET https://contoso.com/api/v1/users/joe.user@contoso.com ]


id              : 00u---------------h8
status          : DEPROVISIONED
created         : 7/31/2015 2:21:58 PM
activated       : 7/31/2015 2:21:58 PM
statusChanged   : 9/30/2016 6:20:50 PM
lastLogin       : 9/27/2016 4:17:37 PM
lastUpdated     : 9/30/2016 6:20:50 PM
passwordChanged : 7/31/2015 2:21:58 PM
profile         : @{firstName=Joe; lastName=User; 
                  login=joe.user@contoso.com; mobilePhone=; 
                  email=joe.user@contoso.com; secondEmail=; region=AM; 
                  PSemployeeID=1----6; department=Chicago-Human Resources; 
                  PSSSOID=1----6; BCPGREDUserName=Joe.user; 
                  organization=Contoso; title=Sr Analyst, 
                  Benefits; employeeNumber=1----6; 
                  ADUPN=joe.user@contoso.com; primaryPhone=+1(312)555-5555; 
                  streetAddress=2-- E--- -------- -----; city=-------; 
                  state=IL; zipCode=-----; countryCode=US}
credentials     : @{provider=}
_links          : @{activate=; self=}

PS C:\Users\perry.harris> oktaActivateUserbyId -oOrg Contoso -username joe.user@contoso.com
[ GET https://contoso.com/api/v1/users/joe.user@contoso.com ]
[ POST https://contoso.com/api/v1/users/0------------------U/lifecycle/activa
te?sendEmail=False ]
{}


activationUrl                                      
-------------                                      
https://contoso.com/welcome/V------------------O

PS C:\Users\perry.harris> oktaGetUserbyID -oOrg Contoso -userName joe.user@contoso.com
[ GET https://contoso.com/api/v1/users/joe.user@contoso.com ]


id              : 0------------------U
status          : PROVISIONED
created         : 2/17/2014 10:25:18 PM
activated       : 10/4/2016 9:55:08 AM
statusChanged   : 10/4/2016 9:55:08 AM
lastLogin       : 9/27/2016 2:36:39 PM
lastUpdated     : 10/4/2016 9:55:08 AM
passwordChanged : 
profile         : @{login=joe.user@contoso.com; mobilePhone=; 
                  email=joe.user@contoso.com; secondEmail=; 
                  firstName=Joe; lastName=User; title=Sr Analyst, 
                  Benefits; department=Chicago-Human Resources; 
                  employeeNumber=1----6; primaryPhone=+1(312)555-5555; 
                  streetAddress=2-- E--- -------- -----; city=-------; 
                  state=IL; zipCode=-----; countryCode=US}
credentials     : @{provider=}
_links          : @{suspend=; resetPassword=; resetFactors=; self=; 
                  changeRecoveryQuestion=; deactivate=}
```

Comment: "*Is there an Okta API call to do X?*" -> [ask Okta support](https://support.okta.com/help/open_case)? Although I do notice their 'help' just tries to offload you to StackOverflow, which is amusing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You have AD user deactivated in AD, that in turn deprovisioned in Okta. Now when you reactivate the user in AD the user and later in Okta, the user is no longer mastered by AD?

If that is the case, once you activate the user in Okta ( via API the request will be POST /api/v1/users/{{userId}}/lifecycle/activate?sendEmail=false ) after activating in AD, you need to run the import for AD. Import will import reactivated user and once you confirm the assignment user will be AD mastered again.

Comment: This is correct.  If I use the web interface I can see confirm the assignment, but I'd like to be able to confirm the assignment programmatically to restore the account to its condition prior to the disablement in AD.

Comment: Import has to be done from UI. There is no programmatic way of running the import. You can set AD settings (under Directory -> Directory Integrations -> AD -> Settings and set the import settings to be auto confirm) to automatically confirm assignment if match is found.